# Regex for a string which do not start with a number and allow only alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a javascript regex for below conditions

- Allow Alphanumeric only
- But also allow underscore(_)
- Don't allow to start with a number
- Don't allow to start with an underscore

I have created a regex `^(?![0-9]|[_].*$).*` which will work for last two conditions above. Please suggest how can I add an `and` condition to make it work for all above scenarios.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]\w*$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]` - any ASCII letter
- `\w*` - zero or more letters/digits/`_`
- `$` - end of string.

To allow an empty string match, wrap the whole pattern with an optional non-capturing group:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]\w*)?$
 ^^^           ^^
```

Comment: What about, Can't contains Underscore as well

Comment: @CharithPrabhagya `\w` matches `_`. So, use `^(?:[A-Za-z][^\W_]*)?$`. Or plainly `^(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)?$`

Answer (score 6):

you can use the regex

```
^[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGhyEq/2)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?![0-9_])\w+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E8ecT6/1)

`(?![0-9_])` is negative lookahead to fail the match when we have a digit or `_` at the start.

Answer (score 3):

You may be thinking too literally about the last two requirements. If it's alphanumeric (so.. a-z and 0-9, right?) then saying "dont allow numbers or underscore at the start" is probably the same as "must start with a letter"

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*$
```

This is "must start with a-z", followed by "must follow with zero or more letters, numbers or underscores. The ^ outside of a character class (for example `[a-z]` is a character class) means "start of input". The $ means end of input.

If you interpreted the last two requirements literally, you could write:

```
[^0-9_]
```

This means "any character that is not 0-9 and also not an underscore" but it doesn't necessarily restrict the user from entering something other than a-z as the first character, so they might enter a #, and it would pass..