# Allow all numbers and string but not starting with any number

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need make form for arabic users can enter her names by arabic and English but enter username by English only and can use all number but not starting with any number and need do smart  by class alert shown when press a false key and hide with true.

```js
// Not Allow Chracter
let EnelementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(
  "#usernameInput, #passwordInput"
);
let ArelementsArray = document.querySelectorAll("#fname, #lname");
function manage(e) {
  var t = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
}
phone.addEventListener("input", function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
});
EnelementsArray.forEach(function (e) {
  e.addEventListener("input", function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9$]/g, "");
  });
});
ArelementsArray.forEach(function (e) {
  e.addEventListener("input", function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Zأ-ي]/g, "");
  });
});
```

```html
<form
  name="login"
  id="regForm"
  action=""
  method="post"
  onsubmit="return doLogin()"
>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">
    <p>أكنب أسمك باللغه عربيه</p>
    <p>
      <input
        name="fname"
        id="fname"
        placeholder="أسم الاول"
        oninput="this.className = ''"
      />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input
        name="lname"
        id="lname"
        placeholder="أسم تاني"
        oninput="this.className = ''"
      />
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <p>البريد هو حسابك علي gmail مثلا forexampl@gmail.com</p>
    <p>
      <input
        name="email"
        type="email"
        placeholder="البريد الاكتروني"
        id="email"
        oninput="this.className = ''"
      />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input
        name="phone"
        type="text"
        placeholder="رقم الموبايل"
        id="phone"
        oninput="this.className = ''"
      />
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <p>
      أنشاء أسم مستخدم وكلمه مرور لك لدخول للإنترنت بيهم باللغه الإنجليزيه فقط
    </p>
    <p>
      <input
        name="username"
        id="usernameInput"
        placeholder="أسم المستخدم"
        oninput="this.className = ''"
      />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input
        name="password"
        id="passwordInput"
        placeholder="كلمة المرور"
        oninput="this.className = ''"
      />
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="footerForm">
    <div class="FormBtn">
      <button type="button" name="act" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1);">
        التالي
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="FormBtn">
      <button
        type="button"
        name=""
        id="prevBtn"
        onclick="nextPrev(-1)"
        disabled
      >
        السابق
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div class="CirclesSteps">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Can I do Phone number format for rtl version and and check if starting by (01) and not min or maxlength for input number in html form

Comment: You have the "I need/want to do this" portion, but it is unclear what specific problems the supplied code is running into.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155282/regex-for-a-string-which-do-not-start-with-a-number-and-allow-only-alphanumeric) or `^(?!\d)(\w+)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.